# ID lost despite left join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using a `left join` to combine two tables based on a common column but I seem to lose the primary key `id` in my left table. Every other column is returned

My controller:

```
$prod_manu = $request->prod_manu;


     return $data  = Product::leftJoin('manufacturers','products.Manufacturer_id','=','manufacturers.id')
    ->where('products.Manufacturer_id',$prod_manu)
    ->get();
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model{   

public function types(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\types','Type_id');
}

public function manufacturers(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\manufacturers','Manufacturer_id');
  } 
}
```

Comment: The condition on the second table needs to go in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because both `Product` and `manufacturers` have an `id` column, so one of them gets overwritten.

Instead of using the left join, you can use eloquent's `with` method.

If you have your relationships and class structure [setup properly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) you should be able to access the `Manufacturer`'s products like this:

```
$manufacturer = Manufacturer::where('id', $prod_manu)->with('products')->get();
return $manufacturer->products;
```

Also note that class names should always be singular and start with a capital letter in laravel. `App\manufacturers` Shouldn't be valid. Please read the article I linked above about setting up your eloquent relationships.

Comment: I edited my relationship definitions and that seemed to fix it. Thank you.